# MySQL query for list all the categories and its description from Magento 2 database?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, query

How to get all the categories and its description from Magento 2 Database using MySQL Query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Get Category Name**

```
SELECT entity_id AS "CATEGORY ID", ccev1.value as "CATEGORY NAME" FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar`as ccev1 JOIN eav_attribute AS ea1 ON ea1.attribute_id = ccev1.attribute_id WHERE ea1.attribute_code = 'name' AND ea1.entity_type_id = 3
```

> **Get Category Description**

```
SELECT entity_id AS "CATEGORY ID", ccev1.value as "CATEGORY DESC" FROM `catalog_category_entity_text`as ccev1 JOIN eav_attribute AS ea1 ON ea1.attribute_id = ccev1.attribute_id WHERE ea1.attribute_code = 'description' AND ea1.entity_type_id = 3
```

Comment: Thank you, If you provide "category_id", "category_name", "category_description" together with a single query. That will fulfill my query completely.